# ¿Por qué el método main recibe como parámetros un array de Strings llamado "args"?

Tags: java

Me gustaría entender por qué el método `main` recibe como parámetros un Array de Strings llamado `args`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

En el parámetro `args` vas a poder acceder al los argumentos pasados al programa por línea de comandos.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tengo un archivo JAR ejecutable llamadao `programa.jar`. Si desde la línea de comandos lo ejecuto del siguiente modo:

```
$ java -jar programa.jar --param1 param2
```

Entonces en la primera posición de `args` tendremos el *string* "--param1" y en la segunda posición el *string* "param2": `["--param1", "param2"]`.

Quizá si estás empezando en la programación este tipo de cosas no te van a interesar mucho ya que lo más seguro es que no las vas a usar, pero es algo que se usa mucho en aplicaciones reales.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada el método `main()` es el método con el cual la aplicación dará inicio, sin este no se ejecutará. Por ello que ha de ser `public` y `static` o `final`.

Del mismo modo el método *main* debe definirse en minúsculas por estándar de Java [(JRE)-Java Runtime Environment-](https://www.ibm.com/co-es/cloud/learn/jre). A la hora de ejecutar el código, el entorno de ejecución de Java (JRE) busca el punto de entrada predeterminado. El JRE solo sabe que es un método llamado *main*. Si no lo encuentra, no puede acceder. Es por ello que puedes considerar *main* como una palabra clave de acceso. Si la cambias, tu aplicación no se ejecutará.

Ahora, **el argumento *args* de *main* en Java**, [¿qué es?](https://javautodidacta.es/metodo-main-en-java/)

El método `main()` acepta un parámetro (y solo uno): una array de tipo `String`. Esta matriz recoge los valores que introduzcas a la hora de ejecutar tu aplicación desde la línea de comandos. Da igual el valor que introduzcas: el JRE lo transformará a `String`.

Este debe aparecer obligatoriamente como argumento del método main en un programa Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Los parámetros que son pasados al método *main* también son llamados parámetros o valores de línea de comando, ya que son pasados desde una línea de comando.
[Aquí](https://www.aluracursos.com/blog/string-args-en-java) explican cómo es esto.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Con mucho gusto!! Si esta respuesta te ha servido, recuerda votar ⬆️, para que a más personas le sirvan! Saludos